# Setting DocumentRoot by cookie value

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, configuration

I am trying to serve different content (other DocumentRooot) for requests containing special cookie value.

When using nginx it was pretty simple:

```
set $newroot "oi-dev";

if ($cookie_interface = "ni") {
    set $newroot "ni-dev";
}
```

and later: `root /path/to/document/$newroot;`

Unfortunately trying to recreate such effect in Apache (using 2.4) is not working as intended.

```
<If "%{HTTP_COOKIE} =~ /interface=ni/">
    Header set droot-matched true
    Define Droot /path/to/document/ni-dev
</If>
<Else>
    Define Droot /path/to/document/oi-dev
</Else>
DocumentRoot ${Droot}
```

It is weird, because control header (`droot-matched`) is sent when proper cookie is set, but Apache still uses `${Droot}` value from `<Else>` section as DocumentRoot.

I've tried also luck with VirtualDocumentRoot, but result was exactly the same.

Am I missing something obvious or there is other method to achieve described effect in Apache?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to achieve the same result to no luck. A pity the response is not here, so I also have the same question, plus a possible explanation to why the Else code is executed...

Am I correct to think both If and Else are evaluated? (this would explain droot-matched is set, and Droot matches the second value).

If the Else statement is removed, the If one works "as expected"?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/509191)